# Notepad ++ Replace All Regular Expression (Start of the line and End of the line)

Tags: notepad++

I am tryin to Replace the start of line with a "(". However when i use replace all i'm not able to do so.

For eg:

```
432425\n
4254645\n
w4546746\n
46457367\n
4765756\n
```

I want the output as using **Replace All**
So i use the ^ symbol with Regular Expression Selected and Replace All.

**Using only Replace works fine.**

```
(432425\n
(4254645\n
(w4546746\n
(46457367\n
(4765756\n
```

Comment: Yes, notepad++ is seriously stupid for this. Wish they had someone fix it, annoying.

Comment: This link explains how notepad++ detects the "start of line" https://superuser.com/questions/146061/notepad-why-does-finding-not-work

Answer (score 15):

Not a solution, but a workaround:

Instead of using Regex's you can use the notepad++ macro feature to record keystrokes and then replay until the end of the file...

1. Put cursor in front of first line
2. Start recording
3. Type a (
4. Press down and left on your keyboard
5. End recording

Replay to end of file

Easier if you don't know Regex's.

Comment: @JD: I haven't tried this. Yet, it seems to be a good way. +1

Answer (score 13):

I don't know why you are having problems.

This works for me in Notepad++ v6.2:

```
Search -> Replace
Search Mode -> Regular expression
Find What: ^
Replace with: \(
Click Replace All
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Currently using 6.3.2 and works perfectly.

Answer (score 12):

A workaround: find `^(.)` and replace with `(\1`.

It seems like a Notepad++ bug to me.

Comment: for this to work, search mode should be regular expression only.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using notepad++, don't bother with the regex.

Instead, use the extended search mode to replace all \n with (

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the rep points to add a comment...

@MrBones

replacing "\n" also needs "\n" as the beginning of the "replace with" so that the file still has \n instead of only "\r".

so for Notepad++

Find what:\n 
Replace with:\n(

Answer (score 1):

This will work  in Notepad++ : before doing replace steps, first copy text to notepad, then copy text from notepad to notepad++,

Search -> Replace
Search Mode -> Regular expression
Find What: ^
Replace with: (
Click Replace All

Answer (score 0):

if you mean replace same as insert `(` on start of the line,
just using this following easy step:

Type:

```
     ^
```

in "Find what" box.

```
    (
```

in "Replace with" box.

Hints:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Editing_Configuration_Files